# Can I include a cpp file in the main when there is a hpp?

Tags: c++, include, program-entry-point

For example:
I have a class called A. And there is:

```
A.hpp
A.cpp
main.cpp
```

for my project

By default, I only need to include A.hpp in the main so I can compile it, either using IDE such as Xcode or using:

```
g++ main.cpp A.cpp -o xxxxx
```

But the submission system only allows me to use:

```
g++ main.cpp -o xxxx
```

I tried to include A.cpp in the main, but the IDE says: main file cannot be included recursively when building a preamble

Is there any solution? I want to keep my hpp and cpp separately.

Comment: One should never include a cpp file.

Comment: what is "the submission system" ? maybe that is what needs to be fixed

Comment: The submission system is school's web submission system, I submit my work and get auto mark. The system will compile my code using g++ main.cpp -o xxxx

Comment: @NathanOliver Unless there is some very weird building system that will only compile one file and nothing else... If OP cannot change that submission system, this may be the only way. Or remove other cpp files and put the code somewhere else.

Comment: Obviously the submission system (whatever that is) cannot deal with more than one .cpp file, therefore you should just put your whole code in a single .cpp file. This can be done without problems. Otherwise ask your teacher/tutor.

Comment: ^ that would be my goto.  Just copy a.h  into the top of main.cpp and paste a.cpp after main's code.

Comment: If you want to know what causes the message _"main file cannot be included recursively when building a preamble"_, you should [edit] the question and show a [MCVE].

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Actually the system allows multiple cpp, and makefile, but for this assignment. The instruction said it will only use g++ main.cpp -o xxxx, so makefile is not an option. The tutor said we can #include "otherFile.cpp" in the main, my friend tried to write a class without header and include like this, it worked. But I' wondering if I can keep both hpp and cpp form my class.

Comment: Do you know what `#include` does?

Comment: I would just use a single source file

Comment: ***main file cannot be included recursively when building a preamble*** Seems like you have a loop where the .cpp files include each other. Make sure that neither file includes `main.cpp`

Comment: @jonapple29 you need to show us a [MCVE]. There is a problem with your `#include`s but without seeing your code we can't do much.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I include a cpp file

In theory, any file can be included.

But as a convention, you should never include cpp files.

> But the submission system only allows me to use:
>
> ```
> g++ main.cpp -o xxxx
> ```

If you cannot compile A.cpp then don't write such file at all. Write the definitions that you would have written in A.cpp into main.cpp instead. This achieves the same as including with a macro, but there won't be duplicate definitions in another cpp file.

Answer (score 1):

You can `#include` any file you want. `#include` is automatic copy-paste. It looks in the file you tell it to include, and it reads whatever's in the file, and it pretends you wrote that in your original file. It doesn't care what's in the file, it just does that. You can include a `.h` file, a `.hpp` file, a `.cpp` file, a `.txt` file, a `.py` file, a `.jpg` file, or anything you want, as long as it's got valid C++ code in it.

Note that including a `.cpp` file is *not the same* as compiling it separately. And people expect that `.cpp` files are compiled separately, not included. To avoid confusing other programmers or the future version of yourself, you *should* rename the file to something else if you want to include it. You don't have to, but you should. If it's not a normal header file either (because you can't include it more than once), then you can make up some completely different extension, like `.inc`.